# How to include external files to node js project while connecting from outside

Tags: javascript, node.js

server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chat">
        <ul id="messages"></ul>
        <input id="m" autocomplete="off">
        <div id="button">Send</div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $('#button').on('click touchstart', function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I start my server on my desktop PC runing windows 8.0 x64 and i forward port on router so then i connect for example from my phone going to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000 (current home ip address) all was working ok until i wanted to include external jquery from my "server" and css file style.css also from the server. I was reading on stack that there is some method called static path so i created inside my project folder "public" and i used:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`
which i found here: [Node.js - external JS and CSS files (just using node.js not express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134554/node-js-external-js-and-css-files-just-using-node-js-not-express)

but not single one method presented on stack worked, it keep returning several errors:

`is not an object`
`is not defined`
or just server starts but file is not found

my hd path is:

```
C:\Users\Patryk\Desktop\nodeproject\index.html
C:\Users\Patryk\Desktop\nodeproject\server.js
C:\Users\Patryk\Desktop\nodeproject\node_modules\...
C:\Users\Patryk\Desktop\nodeproject\public\...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might not have things in the proper order. You need to declare your static paths before your routes. Something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Here is an updated version of your `server.js` file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: the problem is that in this code `express` returns `express is not defined` can you construct the code so it would work under server code i included or briefly instruct me how should i redefine my vars so it wouldnt return these errors ;)

Comment: now with this new code that you provided i got error `path is not defined` why that may be?

Comment: oh i solved it i was just missing `var path = require('path');` in var declarations, and also should be `/public` instead of `public` and now its working, thank you :)