# Node js - socket.io - Linked Stylesheet not loading... port issue?

Tags: html, node.js, websocket, socket.io, server

I have a working chat application ( tutorial here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QISU14OrRbI ) hooked to mysql instead of mongodb.

All of my code in a paste, minus the css : http://pastebin.com/j5FLZyFP

I have always been able to link to a css file via the link element in the DOM head. I am wondering why this approach doesn't work in my example and if it has anything to do with which ports i am using. The server that serves the index.html page is running on port 8080, while my sockets server is running on port 9000. Should I be using the same port for both of them? If so, how do I do that?

Below are screenshots of my browser @ 127.0.0.1:8080

I need 10 reputation to post more than 2 links, slap my wrist I suppose - https[colon][slash][slash]imgur[dot]com[slash]a[slash]22Vv5

I get served the page, but i am forced to press ESC to stop the main.css from getting transferred. Then the remaining requests come through. don't be concerned about inject.js, it represents the Wappalyzer extension and I have tried the example with Wappalyzer disabled.

Adding my CSS to a style tag works and isn't too much trouble to implement in my case, but it would be nice to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Similar question and solution is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134554/node-js-external-js-and-css-files-just-using-node-js-not-express

Comment: So I have to use the 'url' and 'fs' packages to load the (all) external resources? That seems do-able. Thanks a lot! I'll try it out later with fresh eyes and mark as solved if it works.

Comment: Its better to use some node framework like `express`. it will take care of lot of things and you will not have to write everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Kamran Adil in the comments has answered this well. See linked question: [Node.js - external JS and CSS files (just using node.js not express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134554/node-js-external-js-and-css-files-just-using-node-js-not-express?lq=1)

this worked just fine adding a new condition to test the request

```js
    var param = 'main'; /* Stylesheet file name */

if(req.url.indexOf('.css') != -1) {
    fs.readFile('./styles/'+ param +'.css', function (err, data) {
 if (err) { console.log(err); }
 res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'});
 res.write(data);
 res.end();
    });
}
```