# Alternative to sendFile when linked files are not public

Tags: node.js

I'm doing a node project where I expose my public folder like:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')))
```

So now, all my public files are accessible through `localhost:8080/*`

I have also created a folder called "views" where I save private views, javascript and css files associated with them. They are private views so I don't want any user to access them.

As I have html linked with my css files and javascript, when the browser try to GET them, it says "not found" because they are not in the public folder.

I'm sending the html as sendFile in the express route.

Is there any way to put all files in the public folder and then protect them for not being accessible to public users? Or is there any alternative to sendFile, so the file is rendered locally and it doesn't need to request the css and javascript files

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views are *technically* private. Because they are rendered server-side, and not directly accessible by the visitors.

But you generally don't want stuff like Javascript, CSS nor views to be private. They will be seen anyway by the user. The only reason to have things like Node.js views private is the fact that they need be rendered by Node.js prior sending them to the user.

If you have private files, you might want to do same. 
Otherwise, simply place them on the `/public` folder. You should not be hiding any secrets inside your JS / CSS code.

**Edit (following comment):**

You have a couple ways to do that.

Either you build a unique response that contains all necessary HTML / views - CSS - JS.

```
render('view.ejs', { css: 'body { color: blue }' })
```

You will need render that variable into your view, just like you might already be doing with your other views.

You might also want to read it from a file:

```
fs.readFile(`${__dirname}/css/style.css`, (error, styles) => { ... }
```

Or you handle each file request separately:

[Node.js - external JS and CSS files (just using node.js not express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134554/node-js-external-js-and-css-files-just-using-node-js-not-express)

*(if you use Node.js views simply render these one instead of HTML files)*

Comment: Yes you're right, but I was wondering if I could do that. So, is there any way to render the html files with the linked css and javascript files before they are sent to the user, even if those files are not in the public folder?