# I am not able to add CSS files in node JS

Tags: node.js

I am not able to add css and js file please give me a code by which i can use my css or other files 
    This is my code:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const port = 3000;
fs.readFile('index.html',(err,html) => {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }

    const server = http.createServer((req,res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/html');
    res.write(html);
    res.end();
    });
server.listen(port, hostname, () =>{
    console.log("server started on port: "+port)
    });
});


my file location is
test.js
index.html
public /css==>here my css files
       /js ==>here my other js files
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js - external JS and CSS files (just using node.js not express)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134554/node-js-external-js-and-css-files-just-using-node-js-not-express)

Comment: by using this also my css file not included =>> Node.js - external JS and CSS files (just using node.js not express)

Comment: @ashwinichavan try to use ``express``

Comment: i got answer..thanku all

Comment: @ashwinichavan if you were able to resolve your issue, would you mind to post the answer here and accept it ? so that it can help others as well.

Comment: yes of course I will do it @agpt