# How do we display CSS and Pictures through NODE.js WITHOUT Express JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I tried looking for information regarding this but everything includes Express JS which I cannot use for this task.  I need to display index.html with pictures and an external CSS file called styles.css. I am successful in displaying the HTML. For the pictures I also tried using "`<img class="logo" src="http://localhost:8888/pic.png" alt="My_Logo" />"`
This also does not work.

Here is my JS code.

```
var http = require("http"); 
var fs = require('fs');

function onRequest(request,response){
    response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    fs.readFile('./index.html',null,function(error,data){
        if(error){
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write('File not found');
        }else{
            response.write(data);
        }
        response.end();
    });
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8000);
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Project 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <img class="logo" src="http://localhost:8888/pic.png" alt="My_Logo" />
    <div class="head">
      <h1>Social Media Network</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="startHeader">
        <img src="pic1.png" class="bottompic" alt="" />
        <h2>Start Your Network Today</h2>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Im going to try this out : [Node.js - external JS and CSS files (just using node.js not express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134554/node-js-external-js-and-css-files-just-using-node-js-not-express)

Comment: You have to implement routing. Read the request url and method and send a corresponding response, e.g. `if (request.url === '/styles.css') { /* send CSS */ } else { /* send HTML */ }`

Comment: use what's in `request` to determine if it's a request for not index.html, load and serve file accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve static files like CSS and pictures using Node.js without using Express.js, you can use the built-in http module along with fs (File System) module.

```js
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  // Parse the requested URL
  const parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);

  // Get the pathname from the URL
  const pathname = parsedUrl.pathname;

  // Set the content type based on the file extension
  const contentType = getContentType(pathname);

  // Map the requested URL to the corresponding file path
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', pathname);

  // Read the file from the file system
  fs.readFile(filePath, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      // If the file is not found, send a 404 response
      res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
      res.end('File not found');
    } else {
      // If the file is found, send the file content with the appropriate content type
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
      res.end(data);
    }
  });
});

// Function to determine the content type based on the file extension
function getContentType(filePath) {
  const extname = path.extname(filePath);
  switch (extname) {
    case '.html':
      return 'text/html';
    case '.css':
      return 'text/css';
    case '.js':
      return 'text/javascript';
    case '.jpg':
    case '.jpeg':
      return 'image/jpeg';
    case '.png':
      return 'image/png';
    case '.gif':
      return 'image/gif';
    default:
      return 'application/octet-stream';
  }
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```